# Application communication monitoring

Tags: mobile, android, google

I am seeking a way to monitor communication between Android applications in order to detect their suspicious behaviour but I am not sure where to start the development process from.

As far I have found such tool like http://www.comdroid.org/ but its functionality in not what I am looking for. I would like to have app on my mobile that could inform e.g. that app A communicates with apps: B, C and D. I am guessing that kernel programming might be involved.

I would appreciate any hints, directions, literature etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that Tor-based browsers like [Orweb](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orweb/) are likely to get round any detection you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TaintDroid](http://appanalysis.org/) is a modification of android to provide realtime privacy monitoring.

[ProxyDroid](http://code.google.com/p/proxydroid/) forces all communication though a proxy such that it can be intercepted.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you

1. Create a Hotspot on your Laptop
2. Install WireShark on your Laptop
3. Run Wireshark on the your network interface that the HotSpot is on
4. Disable GSM Services on your phone
5. Enable WIFI on your phone and connect to your Hotspot (from step 1)
6. Watch the Traffic flow from your Phone

What I think you will find is ....

Most data is being sent via a SSL connection, making it very difficult to determine what is being sent.

However you should be able to work out which ports are being used - by some reverse DNS tracing.